# App Engine Java and EclipseLink: Deadlock on shared-cache access

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, eclipselink, deadlock, google-cloud-sql

I'm have a Java Maven Google App Engine project configured like follows:

I'm using EclipseLink as JPA persistence-manager for Cloud SQL. My object contains some simple fields (string, date, ...) and a ManyToMany relationship, which is configured as Lazy-Load

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
public class MyObject1 {
    private String nome;

    private String descrizione;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    (
        name = "myobject1_has_myobject2",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "object1_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "object2_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }
    )
    private List<MyObject2> relationshipObjects;
}
```

The project flow works like this:
- A query is made that retrieve x results of type `MyObject1` (let's say 10 results)
- The query results list is iterated and each result is given to a different Thread for processing
- Each thread iterate the ManyToMany relationship (the `relationshipObjects` object), which is Lazy and this in confirmed because the code calls `IndirectList.iterator`, and do some processing for each `MyObject2` item of the list
- When all the threads have finished, the query result of `MyObject1` is iterated once again to create a request response

This kind of implementation is giving some trouble regarding the multi-thread implementation and a some sort of deadlock.
Here is the stacktrace

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-2001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConcurrencyException
Exception Description: Wait was interrupted. 
Message: [null]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConcurrencyException.waitWasInterrupted(ConcurrencyException.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConcurrencyManager.acquireDeferredLock(ConcurrencyManager.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.CacheKey.acquireDeferredLock(CacheKey.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.AbstractIdentityMap.acquireDeferredLock(AbstractIdentityMap.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.IdentityMapManager.acquireDeferredLock(IdentityMapManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.IdentityMapAccessor.acquireDeferredLock(IdentityMapAccessor.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retrieveCacheKey(AbstractSession.java:5200)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
```

I cannot reproduce all the time the problem, besides that I can give you all the information I can gather.

Looking inside the EclipseLink [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_diagnose_and_resolve_hangs_and_deadlocks.3F) I found a section related to this matter

> Cache - If using a shared cache, EclipseLink requires locking the cache on reads and writes to ensure consistency.
>
> You will see cache access, such as IdentityMapManager acquireLock or acquireDeferredLock, or WriteLockManager as the last call on the stack.

In my persistence-unit I did not configure the shared-cache behaviour, so it is running on default which is enabled.
Here is my persistence-unit properties

```
<properties>
    <!-- configure the various connection pool properties -->
    <!-- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool.htm -->
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="1" />
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.min" value="64" />
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max" value="64" />
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.shared" value="true" />

    <!-- whether connections in EclipseLink read connection pool should be shared (not exclusive). Connection sharing means the same JDBC connection will be used concurrently for multiple reading threads. -->
    <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.connection_pool.read.shared" value="true" />

    <!-- specify if JDBC statements should be cached -->
    <!-- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_jdbc_cachestatements.htm -->
    <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true" />

    <!-- the number of statements held when using internal statement caching -->
    <!-- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_jdbc_cachestatements_size.htm#CACBICGG -->
    <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements.size" value="100" />
</properties>
```

I can see in my stacktrace that there is indeed the `IdentityMapManager.acquireDeferredLock(IdentityMapManager.java:146)` row that is referred.

The thing is, this error is thrown by the App Engine request (see last line of stacktrace) when I call the `getResultList` method. 
This call is made by the main request thread, other threads (one for query result) has not been launched yet.

So I started to looking for the shared-cache [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching) and I found this part:

> The shared cache exists for the duration of the persistence unit (EntityManagerFactory, or server) and is shared by all EntityManagers and users of the persistence unit

My EntityManagerFactory instance is instance-shared (I have a static variabile which is initialized at first query).
So at first access (for each App Engine instance) the variabile is initialized and then shared for all the http requests that will be server by the same instance.

I did this sort of "caching" because the deployment descriptor at the first access of EntityManagerFactory is very slow, and even if I can pre-warmup this object, opening a new EMF at every request costs about 1-2 seconds.
So, I open/close a new EntityManager at each flow (and each thread, because EntityManager is not thread-safe) but the EMF object is shared.

Also, there is another line which says

> This is normally related to having relationships that do not use LAZY, ensure all relationship use LAZY.

My ManyToMany relationship is already Lazy, as pointed out before, so even this point cannot be the cause

Basing on that here, I tried to gather all together: 
- EclipseLink `requires locking the cache on reads and writes to ensure consistency`, so the access to this cache is atomic and multiple threads are queued.
- The sharedcache is based on the EMF object
- The EMF object is shared between requests of the same instance

As suggested by EclipseLink [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_diagnose_and_resolve_hangs_and_deadlocks.3F) I tried to disable the shared-cache and all the flow appaers to works, but it is now very slow.
Anyway, this is another point that confirm the problem here is related to the shared-cache of JPA.
This solution is not suitable because, even w/o considering the speed problem, all those request and threads that concurr of get data from the DBMS (while iterating the Lazy list) consumes all the available connections and the DBMS starts on giving connection errors.

Another suggestion from the documentation

```
DeferredLockManager.SHOULD_USE_DEFERRED_LOCKS = false;
```

but the error is still the same, nothing changed (the error is on `IdentityMapManager.acquireLock`, so the deferredLock is not used anyway)

From the App Engine logs I can see that all these requests are killed after 60s timeout, so the `Wait was interrupted` message can be related to all the threads that were waiting to access the shared-cache, but at the end the App Engine deadline killed the request.
Because of that I tried to deploy on basic-scaling (which does not have the 60s deadline) to see if the request is only slower than the dealine or it is truly stuck on a deadlock
Inside the logs there is no error... but the longest requests does not even show. At this point I can think that the erroneous requests are stuck indefinitely and the request logs will not be shown at all.

Another test I made is reducing all the persistence-unit configuration, removing all the shared configuration, like follows

```
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="1" />
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.min" value="64" />
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max" value="64" />
</properties>
```

But the error is still the same. So it is not related to a connection-pool sharing but the multi-thread itself

As ultimate test I tried to remove the multi-thread flow (each query result is processed one-by-one by the main thread) and leaving the shared-cache enabled. 
This is working.

At this point I'm wondering... because the shared-cache is synchronized, so there is a "funnel" that block anyway the multi-thread process, should I use the monothread implementation anyway?

Comment: This is quite long, but I suspect your issue isn't with the shared cache, but the cache within the EntityManager itself.  The EntityManager is not thread safe, and if you are using lazy relationships, those entities read from it won't be thread safe either - accessing the lazy relationships requires query/cache access on the original EntityManager they were read from.  You will want to look into prefetching the relationships your threads are going to access upfront, before giving them access to the entities.

Comment: Sorry for the long post, I thought it was better insert all the test I made to better understand the issue. From your message I'm understanding the the lazy-list should be consumed by the same EM that made the query. But basing on current implementation each iteration is made by a fresh new EM because each object is processed by a different thread (and EM is not thread-safe). I can make the relationship Eager to test this behaviour, but I'm wondering. If the problem is with the lazy-list iteration, why the exception is thrown by the `getResultList` method?

Comment: I went through the stack a bit more, and it shows it is waiting on the object in the shared cache.  This doesn't seem to be involved in a deadlock though, as this thread doesn't hold any locks itself - it is building the base object only, and gets stuck waiting for another thread to finish. seems you went through the faq already https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_diagnose_and_resolve_hangs_and_deadlocks.3F

Comment: I would suggest you obtain frequent thread dumps to see if you can identify problem threads that might cause a backup, and if you can identify  which entities are involved.  From that, you might be able to reduce the burden they are to the shared cache access, or make those entities use an isolated cache and the rest still use the shared cache.  I still believe this issue might be related to passing around entities from one EM to other threads to trigger the lazy relationships, as this is the same as calling queries directly on that EM.  What references do other entities have to MyObject1?

Comment: Using LAZY load for the references solved the problem, but now most of the time is given to the query execution instead of the process itself. At this point, even if this can be a proper solution, I will not use multi-thread because the time consumption is the same.